# Batch and not blocking console

Tags: batch-file, console, windows-xp, console-application, windows-console

I would like to run program from windows console(cmd.exe) and close console after that. now when i do it the console stays opened as long as the program is running.

I would like it to start program, close console and use program.

I double click the batch

```
@c:\somedir\app.exe
```

Comment: Can you please be more specific? From which context you will launch the console or the program? Can you explain the phrase "I would like it to start program, close console and use program."? Can a batch file be used to launch the program without opening the console beforehand?

Comment: @Sga I added more information

Comment: "start" in batch file is the solution, have you tried it?

Answer (score 6):

Use `start`

```
START "title" [/Dpath] [options] "command" [parameters]
```

Example: `start /B "Test" program.exe`

http://ss64.com/nt/start.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm not running Windows right now so I can't try it out, but have you looked into `start`?  You can find more information [here](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/start.mspx?mfr=true).

Another option might be [`call`](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/call.mspx?mfr=true).